# JavaScript function, bugs associated with a function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, slider

My apology that this question is hard to phrase, the title may be misleading. The question is basically related to passing parameters to a function in JavaScript.

These codes below are a function that allows an element to move horizontally. It's used in a slider. My question is specifically related to the **two lines I commented**.

I wrote the function as below in a separate .js file named **common.js** and it works fine:

(Note the two lines I commented)

```js
function animateX(element, target, stepWidth) {     // the stepWidth parameter
    clearInterval(element.timerId);
    element.timerId = setInterval(function () {
        var current = element.offsetLeft;
        var step = stepWidth;                       // This line
        step = current < target ? step : -step;
        current += step;
        if (Math.abs(target - current) > Math.abs(step)) {
            element.style.left = current + "px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(element.timerId);
            element.style.left = target + "px";
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

However, if I write it in this way, there will be a bug:

The transition is gone, when I click on the arrows, the picture immediately moves to the target, instead of sliding to the target.

```js
function animateX(element, target, step) {     // the parameter uses the same name as the local variable
    clearInterval(element.timerId);
    element.timerId = setInterval(function () {
        var current = element.offsetLeft;
        var step = step;                       // This line: stepWidth -> step
        step = current < target ? step : -step;
        current += step;
        if (Math.abs(target - current) > Math.abs(step)) {
            element.style.left = current + "px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(element.timerId);
            element.style.left = target + "px";
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

Moreover, if I write it in this way, it gets worse:

The picture will not move as planned, it will move a little bit then tremble.

```js
function animateX(element, target, step) {          // This line
    clearInterval(element.timerId);
    element.timerId = setInterval(function () {
        var current = element.offsetLeft;
       // Now I understand why this one is wrong.
        // I changed it to step = current < target ? Math.abs(step) : -Math.abs(step);
        // Problem solved.
        step = current < target ? step : -step;
        current += step;
        if (Math.abs(target - current) > Math.abs(step)) {
            element.style.left = current + "px";
        } else {
            clearInterval(element.timerId);
            element.style.left = target + "px";
        }
    }, 10);
}
```

I totally thought these three ways are the same, but they gave me completely different results.

I also thought the third way is better because it has fewer lines. However, it doesn't work.

Can someone please explain to me the difference? I would really appreciate!

Below are the html codes, if you have time, just copy and try it. This html file and the js function are all you need for it to work. You can see the difference without pictures.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0
        }

        ul {
            list-style: none
        }

        img {
            vertical-align: top;
        }

        .box {
            width: 960px;
            height: 540px;
            margin: 100px auto;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
        }

        .inner {
            width: 960px;
            height: 540px;
            background-color: pink;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }

        .inner ul {
            width: 1000%;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        .inner li {
            float: left;
        }

        #imgs li a {
            width: 960px;
            height: 540px;
            display: block;
        }

        #focusD {
            display: none;
        }

        #focusD span {
            position: absolute; /* inner是relative */
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            left: 5px;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -20px;
            background: #000;
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 30px;
            color: #fff;
            opacity: 0.3;
            border: 1px solid #fff;
        }

        #focusD #right {
            right: 5px;
            left: auto;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box" id="box">
    <div class="inner">
        <ul id="imgs">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/d1.jpg" alt="d1"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/d2.jpg" alt="d2"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/d3.jpg" alt="d3"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/d4.jpg" alt="d4"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/d5.jpg" alt="d5"/></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="focusD">
            <span id="left">&lt;</span>
            <span id="right">&gt;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // getElementByID
    function my$(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var box = my$("box");
    // get slider frame
    var inner = box.children[0];
    // get frame width
    var imgWidth = inner.offsetWidth;
    // get ul
    var ulObj = inner.children[0];
    // get div containing arrows
    var focusD = my$("focusD");

    // show / hide arrows
    box.onmouseover = function () {
        focusD.style.display = "block";
    };
    box.onmouseout = function () {
        focusD.style.display = "none";
    };

    var index = 0;
    // click left arrow
    my$("left").onclick = function () {
        if (index > 0) {
            index--;
            animateX(ulObj, -index * imgWidth, 20);
        }
    };
    // click right arrow
    my$("right").onclick = function () {
        if (index < ulObj.children.length - 1) {
            index++;
            animateX(ulObj, -index * imgWidth, 20);
        }
    };

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code looks good .But in the timer may increase the time like 10 to 400 or 500 .

Answer (score 0):

In the second iteration of your function, you create a variable called 'step', which is the same name as one of the function parameters. In the third iteration, you do not create the copy of 'stepWidth' that you need for your function to work. Try creating a variable with a different name to store your copy of 'step'.

```
function animateX(element, target, step) {         
clearInterval(element.timerId);
element.timerId = setInterval(function () {
    var current = element.offsetLeft;
    var stepWidth = step;                          
    stepWidth = current < target ? stepWidth : -stepWidth;
    current += stepWidth;
    if (Math.abs(target - current) > Math.abs(stepWidth)) {
        element.style.left = current + "px";
    } else {
        clearInterval(element.timerId);
        element.style.left = target + "px";
    }
}, 10);
```

}